# Maven Jetty run JNDI configuration

Tags: spring, maven, jndi, maven-jetty-plugin

My project structure looks like this:

```
parent POM 
|-- app-core
|-- app-model
|-- app-services
`-- app-web
```

In my `pom.xml` for  `app-web`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
    <webDefaultXml>src/test/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Hot deployment works properly and have no issues with `mvn jetty:run`

**Question** : app-core uses springs how can I configure this JNDI for **Jetty maven plugin**  in this multi-module hierarchy which should be accessible in app-core module

**Update :**

Have added **pom.xml** like this

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
    <webDefaultXml>src/main/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
    <jettyConfig>src/main/resources/jetty.xml</jettyConfig>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And my jetty.xml looks like this :

```
  <Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="icatDB" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/testDB</Arg>
    <Arg>
<New class="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource">
    <Set name="serverName">localhost</Set>
    <Set name="databaseName">test</Set>
    <Set name="user">sa</Set>
    <Set name="password"></Set>
</New>
</Arg>
</New>
 </Configure>
```

After that when i run mvn jetty:run I get this error

```
Failure: Object is not of type class org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this works for me :

I need to use jettyEnvXml instead of jettyConfig.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.10</version>
    <configuration>
    <webDefaultXml>src/main/resources/webdefault.xml</webDefaultXml>
    <jettyEnvXml>src/main/resources/jetty.xml</jettyEnvXml> 
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

- See this [jetty documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JNDI) for the configuration of JNDI in Jetty
- See this [Maven Jetty documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) for the way how to add the configuration files to the build process

Comment: Have followed your instructions and getting an error kindly check my updated question

Comment: The links are no longer working, because Codehaus ceased to exist. Might be worth updating this to point to the Eclipse Jetty configuration.